# Add ADBannerView to a SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, iad

I'm trying to add an iAd banner to my game over scene, but I don't know how to add UIView to an SKScene.

The app view controller is:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
    {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size andScore:0];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

and the GameOverScene:

```
#import "GameOverScene.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@implementation GameOverScene

+(id)sceneWithSize:(CGSize)size andScore:(NSInteger)score{
     return [[self alloc] initWithSize:size andScore:score];
}
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size andScore:(NSInteger)score{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

        //some stuff here...

        ADBannerView* banner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50)];
        [self.scene.view addSubview:banner];

        //[self.view addSubview:banner];

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Any idea or suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot add `UIView` to `SKScene`. `SKScene` is a part of `SKView`, use it to add iAd banner to the game.

Answer (score 2):

Use NSNotificationCenter. To make it simple for you:

1) Add a AdBannerView in the storyboard inside the SKView. (Or you can add in using code in your ViewController.m)

2) In your ViewController.h define ADBannerViewDelegate and add in this (remember to link the outlet in storyboard)

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;
```

3) In your ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.banner.hidden = YES;
   //Add view controller as observer
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"hideAd" object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"showAd" object:nil];
}

- (void)showBanner
{
    self.banner.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)hidesBanner
{
    self.banner.hidden = YES;
}

//Handle Notification
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"hideAd"]) {
        [self hidesBanner];
    }else if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"]) {
        [self showBanner];
    }
}
```

4) In your Scene.m, in order to display the ad

e.g. player died and you want to show the banner

```
// Show banner when iad loads
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showAd" object:nil]; //Sends message to viewcontroller to show ad.
```

5) In your Scene.m, in order to hide the ad

e.g. player restarted the game

```
// Show banner when iad loads
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hideAd" object:nil]; //Sends message to viewcontroller to show ad.
```

*Advise hide the ad when it's not loaded.

Comment: When I added the code detailed here, I am left with a white block at the top of the screen when the ads are not loaded, how do I fix this?

Comment: did you remember to link the outlet in storyboard?

Comment: I did after I posted the comment, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

http://www.yokeharn.com/workflow-how-to-create-flappy-bird-game-in-3-days-day-3/
Scroll down to Hour 4: iAd. This is a good tutorial which helps you for 90% the last 10 % you can try yourself