# Using UIButton for a game over screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, sprite-kit

I have been attempting to create a game over screen for almost a month and thought I might as well just post my current code and see if anyone could help. I have read many tutorials and watched some good videos but my code always seems so different that I come across errors even after messing around with it for hours. What I am attempting to create is a a button that brings you back to the starting page (made with storyboard) after a collision between my two sprites. I can make the button that brings you back to the starting screen but I would like help with the code that doesn't let it show until the collision detection and where to declare everything for the button. For some reason I always get errors that things can't be used and that they aren't used correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated. My current code:

Viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

// Create and configure the scene.
MyScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

scene.viewController = self;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
} else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

@end
```

MyScene.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface MyScene : SKScene <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;

@end
```

MyScene.m

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@interface MyScene()

@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval lastTimeSceneRefreshed;

@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode* squirrelSprite;
@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode* lightNut;
@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode* appleSprite;

@property NSTimeInterval lastTouch;

@property BOOL atFirstPosition;
@property CGPoint firstPosition;



@end

@implementation MyScene

static const int squirrelHitCategory = 1;
static const int nutHitCategory = 2;

- (instancetype)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
    [self buildBackground];
    [self startScrolling];

    _firstPosition = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.817f, self.frame.size.height * .40f);
    _squirrelSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"squirrel"];
    _squirrelSprite.position = _firstPosition;
    _atFirstPosition = YES;

    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];
    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = squirrelHitCategory;
    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = nutHitCategory;
    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  nutHitCategory;

    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    [self addChild:_squirrelSprite];

    // Declare SKAction that waits 2 seconds
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0];

    // Declare SKAction block to generate the sprites
    SKAction *createSpriteBlock = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        SKSpriteNode *lightnut = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"lightnut.png"];
        BOOL heads = arc4random_uniform(100) < 50;
        lightnut.position = (heads)? CGPointMake(257,600) : CGPointMake(50,600);

        lightnut.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(200,160)];

        lightnut.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = nutHitCategory;
        lightnut.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = squirrelHitCategory;
        lightnut.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  squirrelHitCategory;

        lightnut.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

        [self addChild: lightnut];

        SKAction *moveNodeUp = [SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:-700.0 duration:1.3];
        [lightnut runAction: moveNodeUp];
    }];

    // Combine the actions
    SKAction *waitThenRunBlock = [SKAction sequence:@[wait,createSpriteBlock]];

    // Lather, rinse, repeat
    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:waitThenRunBlock]];

}
return self;
}

- (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
// Updating background nodes
// We don't want to update backgrounds each frame (60 times per second)
// Once per second is enough. This will reduce CPU usage
if (currentTime - self.lastTimeSceneRefreshed > 1) {
    [self backgroundNodesRepositioning];
    self.lastTimeSceneRefreshed = currentTime;
}
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
// Check time since the last touch event
if (touch.timestamp-_lastTouch >= .9) {
    // Allow touch
    NSLog(@"greater than or equal to 3 seconds");

    if (_atFirstPosition)
    {
        SKAction *moveNodeLeft = [SKAction moveByX:-207.8 y:0.0 duration:0.85];
        [_squirrelSprite runAction: moveNodeLeft withKey:@"moveleft"];
    } else {
        SKAction *moveNodeRight = [SKAction moveByX:207.8 y:0.0 duration:0.85];
        [_squirrelSprite runAction: moveNodeRight withKey:@"moveright"];
    }
    _atFirstPosition = !_atFirstPosition;
    _squirrelSprite.xScale *= -1.0;
}
else {
    // Ignore touch
    NSLog(@"Seconds since last touch %g",touch.timestamp-_lastTouch);
}
// Store timestamp
_lastTouch = touch.timestamp;


}

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact

{
NSLog(@"contact detected");
SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

firstBody = contact.bodyA;
secondBody = contact.bodyB;

if(firstBody.categoryBitMask == squirrelHitCategory || secondBody.categoryBitMask == nutHitCategory)
{

}
}

-(void)goToHomeScreen {
[self.viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Please let me know if there is any other information I need to add or anything I should clarify, thank you!

Comment: Is "contact detected" being logged properly? Is that when you want to transition to the home screen?

Comment: It is being logged correctly and I want a little box that says game over with a button to go back to the start screen after it is logged. Thank you!

Comment: In that case, simply present a `UIAlertController` in `didBeginContact:` with a button that triggers the `goToHomeScreen` method.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like help with the code that doesn't let it show until the collision detection and where to declare everything for the button

Use NSNotificationCenter to set the UIButton hidden property to YES or NO.

Comment: it's similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736082/add-adbannerview-to-a-skscene/24794419#24794419